# Polygons drawn in editable feature service through Collector cause reverse or negative geometry

Tags: polygon, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, donut-polygons

I have been experiencing a very odd situation where polygons – when drawn in an editable feature service through Collector on iPad – will draw and save, then seconds later the geometry will be reversed. Instead of drawing a polygon, I end up with a polygon of the entire world with the hole cut out of it where I’ve made my polygon! Really confusing to explain…

Here’s a screen capture of my process in Collector as a test: Here I’ve drawn my polygon but not yet submitted…

[image: Collector - polygon drawn]

After hitting submit, I get this…

[image: Collector - upon hitting submit]

For some reason I’m getting the reverse of the geometry I’m asking for.

I’ve had this problem with some, but not all of the polygon feature services that I’ve created and published to arcgis online.

Ideas?

Comment: are you drawing them clockwise or anti-clockwise?

Comment: Always clockwise, though I tried counter clockwise when I suspected a ring ordering issue... Didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed and will be in the next update of the Collector App which should be out the end of Feb/Early March depending on app store approval times.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Do you know of a work-around until then? What triggers the error?

Comment: collecting the feature counter clockwise seems to be the root of issue. Other than collecting features clockwise I don't have a better work around.